# Get current Windows user — not current user running process

Tags: c#, windows, process, active-directory

How do I get the **current** logged in **Windows user**? my problem: i'm running a process with administrator privileges and all these:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
Console.WriteLine(Environment.UserName);
Console.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User); //GUID
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME"));
```

...tries give me back the current user who runs the **process**, in my case *Administrator* - but i'd like to have the **current user who is logged in**.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666685/c-sharp-net-how-to-detect-if-a-process-is-running-for-the-current-logged-in-use?rq=1

Comment: @UweKeim Not sure how that's a duplicate

Comment: _"i'm running a process with administrator privileges "_ - do you mean the process is running _elevated_? What OS is this because when I add an **app.manifest** and include `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` for my test app, it runs elevated and yet still displays _my name_ correctly and not "administrator" or similar

Comment: @MickyD - that's because you have administrator rights. If you were running as a non-admin, then elevation would also prompt you for an alternate username and password. You can see that sort of thing discussed in the Raymond Chen article I linked at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ahhhh thanks Damien :)

Comment: Related, different language: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28672303/886887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this method a long time ago. I am using the [WMI query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
     new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Comment: I never used this method for 2 users. But the question is not for 2 users?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not a fool-proof method.  _"[In a terminal services session, UserName returns the name of the user that is logged on to the console—not the user logged on during the terminal service session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx)"_

Comment: Oh. For my project it worked, but if that's right: I'm wrong. Sorry

Comment: if current user is not an admin, which run the application, the collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>() include 1 empty item. So, this solution doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 2):

The correct way, I believe, would be to execute [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(v=vs.85).aspx), something along the lines of:

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
                           WTSUserName,buffer, out byteCount);
```

[PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.wtsquerysessioninformation) page for this function.

---

Tangentially related, but may be of interest - [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)